# setting value of minmaxcurve sets the value of other automatically in array

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am Making an array of ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve and the length of the array is 2. When i start making curve of first one, the second one automatically getting the same value.

i tried to make a new array every time but it didn't work out

Comment: Please show your code